# Removing CloudPages Default Styles

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, smart-capture

After building a SmartCapture form in CloudPages, the publish process pushes in "smartcapture-form.css" that overrides much of the CSS I've written. I'm new to SFMC and can't seem to find where to turn this off (if it can be).

Also, it's 2019: why is Salesforce still using tables for layout?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

In Web Studio, create two [Code Resources](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_a_code_resource.htm&type=5), first one being the "reset" CSS and second one your own CSS that you want to apply.

In the "reset" resource, use the following: https://codepen.io/zuzannamj/pen/JjjQVZK.css

Publish both code resources and copy their links.

Link them in the Code View in your CloudPage, first the "reset", then your CSS:

```
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pub.sx.exacttarget.com/reset">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pub.sx.exacttarget.com/mycss">
</head>
```

Comment: Hmm... that didn't fix it. Here's the HTML in the page's Code View: [https://codepen.io/MrCookToYou/pen/eYmYVap.html](https://codepen.io/MrCookToYou/pen/eYmYVap.html). The CSS is being loaded by smartcapture-formjs.js.

Comment: Can you try to including the css from https://use.typekit.net/rtw4koz.css internally directly by pasting it in <style> element in <head> section?

Comment: And try removing it from smartcapture-forms.js if you don’t need it there?

Comment: I moved Typekit to my custom CSS file: no change.